# How to mock generic class

Tags: generics, moles

I would like to mock a behavior of a controller (manager). To get the instance of a manager I use a factory DP. I have a next line of code:

BusinessProcessManagerFactory "<"IEmployeeManager">".Instance.Get();

According to an Interface IEmployeeManager, the factory will return me implementation of that interface (the mapping is in XML file).

I would like to mock the EmployeeManager, how can I do that with .NET Moles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is too general. It basically asks how to mock an arbitrary class. Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I would use moles to return a mock object from the call to Get().  In other words, Mock and Mole together.  I use Moq as my mocking framework, so I would probably do something like this:

```
const int myValue = 17;
Mock<IEmployeeManager> mockEmployeeManager = new Mock<IEmployeeManager>();    
mockEmployeeManager.Setup(mem => mem.DoSomething()).Returns(myValue);
MBusinessProcessManagerFactory.AllInstances.Get = t1 => mockEmployeeManager.Object;
```